# Cloud function query conflict

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Im writing a google cloud function to create chat rooms, the user send a request from the mobile app to firestore with his interests and then a trigger function read all the pending requests in the firestore until find someone to match the user. When this happen the cloud function delete the two requests and create the chat room, but my problem is that if multiple users send requests at the time, the cloud function read the requests that in theory should have already been deleted. This is my code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.firestore();

exports.cargarPeticion = functions.firestore.document('/Requests/{id}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

    const newValue = snap.data();
    const uid = newValue.uid;
    const age = newValue.age;
    const sex = newValue.sex;
    const manInterest = newValue.Hombres;
    const womenInterest = newValue.Mujeres;
    const loveInterest = newValue.Love;
    const friendInterest = newValue.Friendship;
    const timestamp = newValue.Timestamp;
    const minAgeInterest = newValue.ageMin;
    const maxAgeInterest = newValue.ageMax;
    var ciclo = true;

    db.collection('Requests').orderBy('Timestamp').get()
    .then((snapshot) => {

        try{
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                var data = doc.data(); 
                
                if(data.uid !== uid){
                    console.log("NUEVO");
                    console.log(doc.id, '=>', data.uid);

                    if(loveInterest === data.Love || friendInterest === data.Friendship){

                        if(data.age >= minAgeInterest &&
                            data.age <= maxAgeInterest && 
                            ((sex === "H" && data.Hombres === "true") || (sex === "M" && data.Mujeres === "true"))){

                            if(age >= data.ageMin &&
                                age <= data.ageMax && 
                                ((manInterest === "true" && data.sex === "H") || (womenInterest === "true" && data.sex === "M"))){

                                var arrayUsers = [uid, data.uid];

                            console.log("ID SALA");
                            console.log(uid.substring(0, 8) + data.uid.substring(0, 7) + doc.id.substring(0, 7));
                            db.collection('chatRoom').doc(uid.substring(0, 8) + data.uid.substring(0, 7) + doc.id.substring(0, 7)).set({
                                arrayUsers: arrayUsers,
                                uid1: uid,
                                uid2: data.uid,
                                chatRoomId : uid.substring(0, 8) + data.uid.substring(0, 7) + doc.id.substring(0, 7),
                                ultimoMensaje: '',
                                ultimoEscritorUid : '',
                                ultimoMensajeTiempo : 0
                            });

                            db.collection('Requests').doc(doc.id).delete();
                            db.collection('Requests').doc(snap.id).delete();


                            throw exception
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        }catch(exception){
            console.log(exception);
        }

        return null;
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the concurrent database updates from creating an inconsistent data set you'll need to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to perform the update. When using a transaction, the first instance to modify the data is allowed, and any conflicting updates to the same data are automatically retried again until there are no conflicts.